# PHP file changes its extension to ".suspeced"

Tags: php, email

I have two php files on server that keep changing their extension over night. For example, file.php changes to file.php.suspected

What these two files have in common is mail() function. For example,

```
$mail_success = mail($_POST["email_to"], stripslashes($_POST["email_subject"]), stripslashes($_POST["email_body"]), $_app["email_headers"]);
```

There is nothing else that these files have in common. So, something on the server goes through the files over night and apparently dislikes these files with mail() function, changing their extension or rather adding .suspected extension to .php extension.

Comment: _suspected_ or _suspeced_?

Comment: Did you left your ssh open for default (root, root, on port 22) for at least a second? :D

Answer (score 2):

After a couple minutes of googling, it looks like a PHP file changing filetypes is the sign of a hacked server.  [Here is a post on the CPanel forums](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/php-suspected.475761/), where a guy has a similar issue and the other commenters decide that his server had been hacked.

I personally can't give you any advice to secure your site, but perhaps you should head over to SysAdmin or another community and look into making your server more secure.

Comment: Ok, but why only files with mail() are being changed? If website was hacked, wouldn't most files be screwed then ?

Comment: most likely because files containing calls to `mail()` function also contain a backdoor injected by the hacker that allows sending spam emails at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm about 3 years late, but...

I found a piece of [WordPress malware](https://github.com/bediger4000/php-malware-analysis/tree/master/198.71.239.41-2018-05-19a) that does exactly what you describe.
It's something of a cleaner - it has 56 different functions to decide is a given ".php" file name constitutes code that needs to be rendered inoperable.
One of those indicators is a substring of what you say the two renamed files have in common:

```
function ryypkex($content)
{
    if (strpos($content, " = mail(\$_POST[") !== FALSE) {
        return TRUE;
    }
```

If a given filename's contents match a condition, that filename gets its ".php" suffix changed to ".php.suspect".

The two instances of this cleaner that my honey pot caught use the "RC" action of the WSO web shell to immediately execute the cleaner. No on-disk cleaner code will exist. The implication is that you probably need to look for a WSO web shell somewhere in your web apps' code.